# How to test if OpenGL application works against some particular OpenGL version?

Tags: opengl, lwjgl, backwards-compatibility

Recently I realized my application is using an OpenGL call which is available only on OpenGL 4.5 - [glCreateTextures](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glCreateTextures.xhtml), and I realized it only because I was trying to run the application on a MacOS computer supporting only OpenGL 4.1 and it crashed there.

The application requests OpenGL 4.0 core profile, 3.2 core profile and 3.2 forward compatible core profile (in this order), but in spite of obtaining a 4.0 profile a call to `glCreateTextures` succeeds without any warning.

I would like my application to run on anything supporting 3.2, but I do not have a regular access to hardware which does not actually support 4.5. There might be other issues like this both in API and shader use lurking around which prevent compatibility with lower OpenGL versions and I would like to know about them.

How can I test my application to make sure it works with some particular version of OpenGL (3.2, 4.0) without actually running it on a hardware which does supports newer version?

In my case the application is running on JVM (written in Scala or Java) and uses LWJGL + GLFW bindings, but even knowing how do this for native C/C++ applications would be helpful, if there is a way, it should be probably possible to transform it into the JVM world.

Answer (score 2):

This is a general problem with OpenGL and there not being a difference between loading a core function and an equally-named extension function.

In the case of `glCreateTextures`, this OpenGL function both comes from the `ARB_direct_state_access` extension as well as from OpenGL 4.5 (where that function became core) with equal name.

What actually happens in the concrete context of LWJGL is that it will check at runtime whether the context supports OpenGL 4.5 (there is a definitively function for that since OpenGL 3.0 which allows to check whether an OpenGL context supports a particular core version). And LWJGL will find that this check returns *false* when you request a core profile e.g. 3.3 core.

*However*, LWJGL *also* checks the existence of every advertized OpenGL extension and loads the function pointers of all exposed functions from those extensions.
And in your case, when you request e.g. a 3.3 core context, but your driver *still* exposing `ARB_direct_state_access` (which is perfectly fine) then LWJGL *will* load the function pointer for `glCreateTextures` just fine.
And since there is no difference in routing GL function calls in LWJGL when you call it through a core GL class or through an extension class (it's still the same underlying GL function after all), the call will succeed.

Now to solve this problem, there is a GitHub issue to allow an LWJGL client to *exclude* certain extensions from being loaded: https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3/issues/683

Once this has landed in an LWJGL 3 release, functions that are not core in your requested GL core version will not be visible/available when you *also* exclude the extension.

Another way to at least reduce the risk of using a GL function that comes from a higher GL version than the one your app is targeting, is to simply not use any methods from a `org.lwjgl.opengl.GLxyC` class where `x.y` is higher than the GL version your app is targeting.

So in effect, when you say:

> Recently I realized my application is using an OpenGL call which is available only on OpenGL 4.5 - glCreateTextures, and I realized it only because I was trying to run the application on a MacOS computer supporting only OpenGL 4.1 and it crashed there.

then one can argue that this is on you. Because it means that you were *deliberately* using an OpenGL function from a GL45 class, so you *wanted* to target OpenGL 4.5.

Comment: I use some 4.5  functions deliberately, however optionally (when I detect the OpenGL is at corresponding version). Still, that means I have them imported and it is easy to use them (or some other 4.5 functions) accidentally elsewhere.

Comment: To verify I understand correctly what you write about extensions - does this mean the problem does not exist in a native world, and using `glCreateTextures` from a C source with a 4.0 core profile would actually fail?

Comment: I understand it is my task, but it would be nice to have some tool, technique or anything to help me. It feels lonely to having fight it on my own. One wonders: does it really have to be this way? And how is it with GLSL: when I request `#version 330` in the shader, can I be sure the compilation will fail if I use some 4.x feature?